# Flatbuffer writing in binary file in android give only single response

Tags: java, android, flatbuffers

I am new at flatbuffer. I had created a schema file from outside the project and adding the user(Monster as in Flatbuffer document) inside the binary via java code in android. everything works fine. but the time of reading binary file data it only gives me the user length 1. I had added 3 people but it's give me the length of monsters is 1 at the time of reading. can anyone help to figure this out. Here is the code->

this is the full code ->

enter code here

```
  builder = new FlatBufferBuilder(1024);

  public void addNewData(String emailOffset, String nameOffset,String 
  contactNoOffset, String DOJOffset, String departmentOffset, 
  String empIdOffset, float[] embeddingOffset)

  {
   int storeembedd = SingleJson.createEmbeddingVector(builder, 
    embeddingOffset);
    int hereEmailOffset = builder.createString(emailOffset);
    int hereNameOffset = builder.createString(nameOffset);
    int hereContactOffset = builder.createString(contactNoOffset);
    int hereDOJOffset = builder.createString(DOJOffset);
    int hereDepartmentOffset=builder.createString(departmentOffset);
    int hereImpIdOffset = builder.createString(empIdOffset);


    int test = SingleJson.createSingleJson(builder, hereEmailOffset, 
               hereNameOffset, hereContactOffset
             , hereDOJOffset, hereDepartmentOffset, hereImpIdOffset, 
              storeembedd);

    int [] offsetOfMonster = new int[1];
    offsetOfMonster[0] = test;
    int temp = Monsters.createMonstersVector(builder, 
    offsetOfMonster);

    Monsters.startMonsters(builder);
    Monsters.addMonsters(builder, temp);
    int orc =  Monsters.endMonsters(builder);



    builder.finish(orc);

    byte[] buf1 = builder.sizedByteArray();

    openAndAppenedInBinary(buf1);
}


private void openAndAppenedInBinary(byte[] buf1) {
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        if (inputStream.available() == 0) {
            output = new FileOutputStream(newFile(), true);
            output.write(buf1);
        } else {
            while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                output = new FileOutputStream(newFile(), true);
                output.write(buffer);
                output.write(buf1);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

private String newFile() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + context.getPackageName()
            + "/binFile");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.mkdir()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                try {
                    Path dir = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    Files.createDirectory(dir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Path parentDir = Paths.get(file.getParent());
                    if (!Files.exists(parentDir)) {
                        try {
                            Files.createDirectories(parentDir);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    File binFile = new File(file, "renamed.bin");
    try {

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(binFile);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return binFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

here is my reading code of flatbiffer->

new FlatParsingForPerticularId().execute(readRawResource(R.raw.renamed));//renamed is my bin file

private class FlatParsingForPerticularId extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        byte[] buffer = (byte[]) params[0];
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        Monsters monsterList = Monsters.getRootAsMonsters(bb);
        int length = monsterList.monstersLength();
        SingleJson monster = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {//here I m getting length 1 intead of 3
            monster = monsterList.monsters(i);
           if (i == outputval[0]) {
                outputval[0] = (int) monster.EmpNo();
                break;
            }
        }


        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        String textToShow = "Elements: " + monsterList.monstersLength() + ": load time: " + endTime + "ms";
        String[] monsterArr = monster.Name().split(" ");
        return monsterArr[0];
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more detail to be able to see what is going on: schema, full writing code, full reading code, and details on how the bytes are transferred between the two.

Comment: @Aardappel hey this is the full code I used.

Comment: In your description you say you write 3 people, but in your code you write only 1 to the monsters vector? And it the above still doesn't contain any reading code or schema.

Comment: @Aardappel addNewData() is a method in which I pass the three peoples data in a loop, so the method is called by three times with different data's.And all are append in a binary file via fileoutputstream one by one(and at last I can see their is three data appended in bin file).but when I get read these data from the Monster file of java. it gives me the length of the binary that is 1. if you want to see the reading code and schema I can upload it too.reading code is as usual as they provided in the doc.

Comment: @Aardappel uploaded my reading code, I m getting length 1 instead of 3, as you can see in comment.

Comment: @Aardappel Is appending is really possible in flatbuffer bin file at time by time?

Comment: Like I said, you're only writing a single person per FlatBuffer. Even if you write 3 into a file, getting the "root" of the first one only allows you to access the first. You either need to write 3 persons to your `offsetOfMonster` array instead, or use size prefixed buffers, and process them one at a time.

Comment: @Aardappel I got your first way of adding 3 data of persons's in the array.but I have to modify the bin file time by time as person's are added by the user.like today one person added , tomorrow another. can it be possible with your second way of size prefixed buffers, no matter if the number of persons are fix like here 3.if possible then please suggest me the code.thank u Sir.